# Sql query bring wrong results

Tags: mysql

I have problem with debugging this query, which brings me wrong results...2 records instead of one.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.filterid as filterid2 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT a.*, f.`filterid` 
FROM adds a 
JOIN adds_filters f 
ON a.`addid` = f.`addid` 
WHERE a.`catid` = 1 
AND f.`filterid` = 67 ) t1 

JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,f.`filterid` 
FROM adds a 
JOIN adds_filters f 
ON a.`addid` = f.`addid` 
WHERE a.`catid` = 1 
AND f.`filterid` = 68 ) t2 

JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,f.`filterid` 
FROM adds a 
JOIN adds_filters f 
ON a.`addid` = f.`addid` 
WHERE a.`catid` = 1 
AND f.`filterid` = 158 ) t3 
ON t1.addid = t2.addid
```

Since the tables are fairly long, here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fba45/1)

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Regards, John

Comment: Your fiddle is giving me a single result... So I am unsure where the problem would be. What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you want in your last line

```
    ON t1.addid = t2.addid and t2.addid =t3.addid;
```